# NoClassDefFoundError when using Powermock

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, easymock, powermock

I'm running a `junit` test case using the `PowerMock` test runner.
I'm using the following command line to execute it:

```
java -cp .:junit-4.9b2.jar:easymock-3.0.jar:powermock-easymock-1.4.8-full.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore SampleTest
```

When doing so I am receiving this error:

```
initializationError(SampleTest)
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/junit/internal/runners/TestClassRunner
...
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 89):

I just solved this one now, when I added the `@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)` attribute, `eclipse` automatically imported:

```
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.legacy.PowerMockRunner;
```

All I needed to do is change it to be:

```
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;
```

And now it works fine with `JUnit 4.8.2`.

The 2nd runner is for when running with older versions of `JUnit` - specifically `4.3` and older.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. For anyone using maven, this may also be caused by using wrong powermockito-junit dependency. Make sure that `powermock-module-junit4-legacy` is included for **junit4.0-4.3** and `powermock-module-junit` for **junit4.4 or newer**. Check [this pom configuration](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Mockito-2-Maven#junit-40-43)

Answer (score 7):

See [here](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/FAQ)

> You're probably using the wrong PowerMockRunner. There's one runner made for JUnit 4.4 and above and a second runner made for JUnit 4.0-4.3 (although the latter also works for some older minor versions of JUnit 4.4).
>   Try switching from the org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner to org.powermock.modules.junit4.legacy.PowerMockRunner or vice versa. Look at the [getting started guide](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/Mockito_maven) to see how to configure this in maven.

Answer (score 7):

This Exception occurs when you Import the legacy version of PowerMockRunner.class when using JUnit 4.X or higher version since this legacy class is not available to run when using it with @RunWith annotation. I have solved this issue by replacing older legacy version import with the new version.

**Incorrect Import:**

```
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.legacy.PowerMockRunner;
```

**Correct Import:**

```
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;
```

Comment: Although it is mentioned in the power mock maven setup that 4.0-4.3 junit should use powermock-module-junit4-legagcy artifact, but the above error occurs.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem. I used old version junit-4.0.jar. But I still don't understand why is missing the class TestClassRunner especially in the package powermock-easymock-junit-1.4.8.zip (there is junit-4.8.2.jar)? The junit-4.8.2.jar is missing the class TestClassRunner also.

Comment: This is not the correct solution - merely a workaround. See my answer

Answer (score 0):

I am using JUnit 4.0 - 4.3 and I updated my maven dependency to use powermockito 2.0.0-beta.5 version. It just started working.

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
    <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0-beta.5</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
    <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito2</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0-beta.5</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
```