# Type [unknown] not present Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/junit/internal/runners/TestClassRunner

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, junit

We are upgrading from junit-4.2 to junit-4.10. But with that, I am getting initializationError when launching firefox with below error stack. There is absolutely no reference to TestClassRunner (a class from junit-4.2) but not sure why we get it?

```
Type [unknown] not present

java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type [unknown] not present
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.value(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/junit/internal/runners/TestClassRunner
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:803)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:803)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:278)
at java.lang.Class.initAnnotationsIfNecessary(Class.java:3281)
at java.lang.Class.initAnnotationsIfNecessary(Class.java:3288)
at java.lang.Class.initAnnotationsIfNecessary(Class.java:3288)
at java.lang.Class.initAnnotationsIfNecessary(Class.java:3288)
at java.lang.Class.getAnnotation(Class.java:3229)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
```

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/5292440/95725

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the issue was little difference. There were two classes of same name WebDriverRunner. The one that was getting loaded first (based on classpath entries) was incorrect (rather deprecated) one which had some reference of TestClassRunner class. After putting the other jar (with right WebDriverRunner) before the previous one resolved the issue. Thanks all for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

1. Right click your project in Package Explorer > click Properties.
2. Go to Java Build Path > Libraries tab.
3. Click on 'Add Library' button.
4. Select JUnit.
5. Click Next.

OR

Run `mvn clean compile test-compile`

Tell me if it doesnt work, but it worked for me.

Comment: I am not using any ide for this. I am running it using ant script.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this issue but not due to any code changes. In my case I was running a simple Robolectric test on the Android SDK 29 (as it was set in the TestConfiguration). I tried restarting Android Studio, cleaning the build and Invalidating cache but in the end this issue was resolved by changing the SDK to 28 in the Edit Configuration. I also don't have any solid reason to why this worked.