# the import org.junit.Rule cannot be resolved

Tags: maven, junit, junit4

After upgrade some dependencies' versions - I got this error:

`the import org.junit.Rule cannot be resolved`

Anybody know about changes in the packaging or something else that can help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The import org.junit cannot be resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15105556/the-import-org-junit-cannot-be-resolved)

Comment: Maybe it was transient dependency that was removed due to upgrades? If it was only as transient dependency it is not in your pom. In that case add it there as a new dependency.

Answer (score 1):

I catch the troublemaker:

the dependency that changed is "powermock-module-junit4" that I change it to "powermock-module-junit4-**legacy**".

The "powermock-module-junit4-legacy" depends on Junit 4.3, instead of Junit 4.12...

I added an implicit dependency for Junit4.12 and the problem was resolved.

Now I have to check what is "powermock-module-junit4-legacy" and how to **not** use it...

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5292440/noclassdeffounderror-when-using-powermock

Comment: Ok, I have a big mistake, and I can return use "powermock-module-junit4" instead of "powermock-module-junit4-legacy".