# NoClassDefFoundError when using @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, easymock, powermockito

I am running a junit test case using the PowerMock test runner.

When I'm running the class, I'm receiving this error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/powermock/tests/utils/TestSuiteChunker
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.powermock.tests.utils.TestSuiteChunker
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 29 more
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: What versions of PowerMock libraries you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe some wrong auto-imports from your IDE? See this answer: [NoClassDefFoundError when using Powermock](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6578454/811708)

Also, please share the piece of code (with imports) you're trying to run.